# Delete tag "discriminación"

Tags: soporte

Yesterday I saw a user really upset that posted [a question that was really a rant](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12690/5481) about the site itself. The question could actually have been a *meta* question but it seems that this user didn't want to listen to reason, in spite of complaining about the lack of kindness of certain member of the site.

This user seemed to have reputation enough to propose new tags and created the tag "discriminación" for his question-rant.

Could we delete this tag? I don't think it is useful and could lead to confusion. It is obviously not meant to be used to tag our regular questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are currently no questions with that tag, that tag will be automatically removed after a certain period (30 days, I believe).